# How to add dependency's $(ProjectDir) to dependent project's include directories?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions, header-files, visual-c++-2005

I have 100+ projects in solution. For each project, its public headers are located in its project directory. So I want to not keep large lists of include folders for each project, but force VS to do it for me, i.e. if project A depends on B, then not only B.lib is added to link of A, but also B's project dir is added to A's includes implicitly.

Thanks!